# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory : 'C:/Sublime Codes/

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

Here is my code:

[image: Here is my code]

My code and the file are in the same directory but I can't seem to find the error.

Comment: Please, post text as text. not an image. Also, please refrain from using all caps in your text. Many would consider it rude and be automatically much less likely willing to help you.

Comment: Thank you! Will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that maybe path with space was validate wrong.

Please, try to write something like this C:\Sublime/ Codes/Chatbot maybe it will help you.

Comment: i did try nothing happened